# Collection Selector as Lambda Expression with SelectMany

Tags: c#, expression

Combinding an enumerable and a queryable via a Cross Join can be written in Linq like this with SelectMany:

```
 SomeClass[] AnArray = new SomeClass[] {
   new SomeClass { ... },
   ....
 };

 IQueryable<SomeClass> Outer = AnArray.AsQueryable();
 IQueryable<SomeEntity> Inner = <DbConext>.SomeEntity;

 var Crossed = Outer.SelectMany(
   x => Inner,
   (outer, inner) => new { Outer = outer, Inner = inner }
 );
```

Not sure how to create the Collection Selector with Expression Trees?

```
 // Collection Selector
 var OuterAsX = Expression.Parameter(
   Outer.ElementType,
   "x"
 );

 var CollectionSelector = Expression.Lambda(
   ? // <- Some sort of Member Access on Inner
   OuterAsX
 );

 ....

 MethodInfo SelectMethod = (typeof(Queryable))
   .GetMethods()
   .Where(
     method => method.Name == "SelectMany"
       && method.IsGenericMethod
       && method.GetParameters().Length == 3
   )
   .OrderBy(x => x.ToString().Length)
   .First()
   .MakeGenericMethod(
     Outer.ElementType,
     Inner.ElementType,
     ResultType
   );

   IQueryable Query = Inner.Provider.CreateQuery(
     Expression.Call(
       null,
       SelectMethod,
       Outer.Expression,
       CollectionSelector,
       ResultSelector
     )
   );
```

Looking at the Expression from Linq (i.e. the Crossed variable) it defines a Constant around class that has two fields, one of which is the Entity (i.e. Inner), making a member access expression:

```
 Operand    {x => value(Charting.Tests.Engine.GraphTest+<>c__DisplayClass33_0).Inner}
 DebugView  ".Constant<Charting.Tests.Engine.GraphTest+<>c__DisplayClass33_0>(Charting.Tests.Engine.GraphTest+<>c__DisplayClass33_0).Inner"
```

Comment: There is a single problem, when you do this **new { Outer = outer, Inner = inner }** C# compiler create a anonymous type, and doing that dynamically, with Expression Tree, it will not be created automatically

Comment: Ended up creating a dynamic type at runtime (thanks TypeBuilder) with a single field of type IEnumerable<Entity> and set the Inner Queryable to that field in a created instance.  Then made a Expression.Constant out of that object and did a MakeMemberAccess.  Feels awkward but it mirrors what Linq is doing under the hood.